# Marketing Cloud Sender Authentication Package - Creation of Email Addresses

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio, custom-domain, sender-authentication-package

For the purpose of (sending out) marketing-related campaigns, new email addresses should be created in conjunction with the newly established sub-domain (part of the sender authentication package - in short, "SAP). The domain setup has already been completed and verified by Salesforce. In our case, we opted for self-hosting the DNS using an existing sub-domain w own.

Now the question arises if the actual creation of the email addresses meant to be used for campaigns (e.g., "xyc@newsletter.company.com") need to be created on our end, or is it something that needs to be handled by Salesforce? The internal IT team is claiming it needs to be done by Salesforce as the MX- and SPF records point to Salesforce. Does anyone know?

Comment: The email addresses used for sending aren’t meant to be “real” email addresses, so technically nobody needs to create them. You will use RMM to handle and route all replies, so the sending email addresses are just for sending and do not need to physically exist anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So basically we can use any email address as long as it 'ends' with the established and verified domain? Beyond, is it required to enter the email somewhere in the setup, for example From Address Management / Sender Profiles / Delivery Profiles / Send Classification?

Comment: Yes, you can use anything before the `@` symbol and you need to include the sending email address in the Sender Profile/Profiles. No need to add it anywhere else. You can, but don’t have to configure your own Send Classifications. Delivery Profiles serve a different purpose. Please look at the documentation and also make sure you correctly configure RMM to be able to receive replies.

Comment: That's great. Just one last open point for clarification in terms of deliverability:

Does a "virtual" e-mail address have any disadvantages compared to a "real" e-mail address - especially with regard to the deliverability of e-mails? That is, do email service providers also verify the actual existence of an e-mail address, or does only the domain and related IP address play a key role in classifying confidentiality and authenticity - to eventually pass the email through the email server as it was classified as trustful?